# Cómo reemplazar contenido de una columna por otro dato?

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de cambiar la palabra ASESO por ASESOR en una columna ""no es el nombre de la columna es el contenido para una consulta lo estoy intentando con un CASE pero me sale error
como puedo remplazar estos datos para verlo solo en la consulta

gracias de antemano

```
SELECT 
IIDEIN Cedula
,IRAZON Nombre
,ICANAL Canal
,ITIPOI Agencia
,FCODCA Cargo
,INTSUC Cod_Sucursal
,ICIUFI Sucursal
,IESTAD Estado
,FCODAG Agencias_FV
,FCEDSU Superior
,FFECIA Fecha_Ingreso
,FFECNA Fecha_Nacimiento
,IEMAIL Email,

CASE FCODCA = 'ASESO' THEN FCODCA = 'Asesor'

 FROM SVCARTERA.INTERMF
where IIDEIN IN (80082673,40990691,13870673,1033716887)')
```

Comment: 1. No es necesario gritar :) 2. Decís que sale error, pero no mencionás _cuál error_. Pulsá en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Leé [ask]. Y por las dudas... ¿qué los `CASE` no iban acompañados de un `WHEN`? (no manejo SQL Server, lo pregunto desde mi ignorancia)

Comment: Ese openquery en qué fuente está corriendo la consulta? Se ve que openquery es de sqlserver, pero lo de adentro, dónde corre? Como siempre, de eso depende la respuesta

Comment: la consulta corre bien solo no he podido remplazar el contenido de la columna es como un buscar y remplazar de excel pero en sql  y solo es para la consulta no quiero realizar un uptate solo es para visualización

Comment: Eso es claro, pero la sintaxis va a cambiar dependiendo de dónde corre esa consulta que está corriendo en [openquery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), pues ahí no aplica necesariamente la sintaxis de MSSQL si eso viene de Access o Sybase o lo que sea. ¿Se entiende la pregunta? Por favor, pon cómo están mostrándose los datos (con datos de prueba, lo que sea) cuando corres la consulta así como la muestras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que seguir la sintaxis correcta del `CASE`

```
SELECT 
     IIDEIN AS Cedula
    ,IRAZON AS Nombre
    ,ICANAL AS Canal
    ,ITIPOI AS Agencia
    ,FCODCA AS Cargo
    ,INTSUC AS Cod_Sucursal
    ,ICIUFI AS Sucursal
    ,IESTAD AS Estado
    ,FCODAG AS Agencias_FV
    ,FCEDSU AS Superior
    ,FFECIA AS Fecha_Ingreso
    ,FFECNA AS Fecha_Nacimiento
    ,IEMAIL AS Email
    ,CASE WHEN FCODCA = 'ASESO' THEN 'Asesor' ELSE FCODCA END AS FCODCA 
 FROM SVCARTERA.INTERMF
where IIDEIN IN (80082673,40990691,13870673,1033716887)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es no traer la columna sin más sino aplicar el CASE **dentro** de los campos del select.

Si es algo como as400, sería

```
SELECT 
IIDEIN Cedula
,IRAZON Nombre
,ICANAL Canal
,ITIPOI Agencia

,case when FCODCA = 'ASESO' THEN 'Asesor'
    ELSE FCODCA end as Cargo

,INTSUC Cod_Sucursal
,ICIUFI Sucursal
,IESTAD Estado
,FCODAG Agencias_FV
,FCEDSU Superior
,FFECIA Fecha_Ingreso
,FFECNA Fecha_Nacimiento
,IEMAIL Email,



 FROM SVCARTERA.INTERMF
where IIDEIN IN (80082673,40990691,13870673,1033716887)')
```